# How to make rowMeans of data frame where column name is same in r

Tags: r

I have following table

```
x | y | z | x | y | z
0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

I want to rowMeans only on columns that have same name. Since I have three distinct column name i want resulting data frame with three column, each column representing rowMeans of that columns with have same name

So basically, I want following output

```
x   | y   | z   |
0.5 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
1   | 1   | 1   |
0   | 0   | 0   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `split`

```
sapply(split.default(df1, names(df1)), rowMeans)
#      x   y   z
#[1,] 0.5 0.5 0.5
#[2,] 1.0 1.0 1.0
#[3,] 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(0L, 1L, 0L), y = c(1L, 1L, 0L), z = c(1L, 
 1L, 0L), x = c(1L, 1L, 0L), y = c(0L, 1L, 0L), z = c(0L, 1L, 
 0L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(unique(names(df)), function(a) rowMeans(df[which(names(df) == a)]))
#       x   y   z
#[1,] 0.5 0.5 0.5
#[2,] 1.0 1.0 1.0
#[3,] 0.0 0.0 0.0
```